# Is there any way to create user specific table "pointers" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

## Question:

Is there a way to make view `PERSON` for user `jack` point to some main person table, lets call it `MAIN_PERSON` and also to create a view `PERSON` for user `jill` and have it point to that same `MAIN_PERSON` table, the difference being, for example, that `jack` has access to only the men, and `jill` only has access to the women.

## Details:

Here is how I would like to set up my tables/views

**PERSON table:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person
(
   id            INT NOT NULL auto_increment,
   male          BOOLEAN,

   PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
engine=innodb;
```

**View for jack:**

```
CREATE VIEW person_for_jacks_eyes_only
AS
SELECT * FROM person
WHERE
person.male = TRUE;
```

**View for jill:**

```
CREATE VIEW person_for_jills_eyes_only
AS
SELECT * FROM person
WHERE
person.male = false;
```

**Create users and grant privileges:**

```
GRANT SELECT ON DB.person_for_jacks_eyes_only TO jack@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '1234';
GRANT SELECT ON DB.person_for_jills_eyes_only TO jill@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '1234';
```

## Motivation:

I want to give different users access to only a subset of the **rows**. From my understanding, this is one of the purposes of views (the other being to combine multiple tables together). I, however, do not want to have obscure view names like `person_for_jacks_eyes_only`, hence why I want to make user specific `local` names. If this is the wrong way to use views, could someone please be as kind as to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not. There is a single global namespace for tables and views; there is no way to create multiple views with the same name.

I believe you could, however, declare a view whose output depends on the current user:

```
CREATE VIEW limited_person AS
    SELECT * FROM person
    WHERE person.male = (USER() = 'jack@localhost')
```

Comment: thanks, that was going to be my next question: whether `USER()` would get executed and stored in the view, or stored and then executed by the view.